# How to "chain" iterators?

Tags: python, iterator

I'm trying to chain iterators together with one iterator reading from a master file and another iterator taking each line of the master file and processing another file depending on the output of the first.

The working code that I have is as follows

```
class MasterReader(object):

    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.f = open(filename, "r")

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        line = self.f.readline().strip()
        if line == "":
            raise StopIteration
        return line


class SubReader(object):

    def __init__(self, mr):
        self.mr = mr

    def __iter__(self):
        self._next()
        return self

    def _next(self):
        self.current = open(self.mr.__next__(), "r")

    def __next__(self):
        while True:
            line = self.current.readline().strip()
            if line == "":
                self._next()
                continue
            return line


mr = MasterReader("master")
sr = SubReader(mr)

for line in sr:
    print(line)
```

Where `master` is a file containing lines of other files

```
file1
file2
```

`file1` contains

```
1.a
1.b
1.c
```

`file2` contains

```
2.a
2.b
2.c
```

The output is

```
1.a
1.b
1.c
2.a
2.b
2.c
```

Again what I have works, but feels wrong in that I have a `while` loop in `__next__` I'm having to manually check for the end of each sub file and explicitly calling the next line in the `master` file.

Is there a better/more pythonic way of doing this?

EDIT:
This is a simplified problem of what I'm trying to accomplish.  In the real version `SubReader` is going to be threaded and I only want one `MasterReader`.  Actually this won't work for my threading project but want to make sure I'm generalizing iterators before diving deeper into a mess.

Comment: Did you try `itertools.chain`?

Comment: @PaulRooney I looked at that but looks like it will process the first iterator then the second.  I need first element of the first iterator then all of the second depending on the first.  Then second of the first then all of the second again.  I'll take a look at `chain` again though.

Comment: It is long (there are three parts) but this pycon video might be of interest...[A Curious Course on Coroutines and Concurrency](http://pyvideo.org/pycon-us-2009/pycon-2009--a-curious-course-on-coroutines-and-co.html) - there are som producer/consumer examples in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the file object is itself an iterator, you don't necessarily need to implement a `__next__` in both cases, just *yield* lines from it in your `__iter__`. More so, reading the file with a *for* loop implicitly handles EOF:

```
class MasterReader(object):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.f = open(filename)

    def __iter__(self):
        for line in self.f:
            yield line.strip()
        self.f.close()


class SubReader(object):
    def __init__(self, mr):
        self.mr = mr

    def __iter__(self):
        for filename in mr:
            with open(filename) as f:
                for line in f:
                     yield line.strip()
```

Comment: yielding rather than returning make all the difference.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `itertools.chain.from_iterable` with the help of small function yielding the stripped lines from each file.

```
from itertools import chain

def fgen(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        for line in f:
            yield line.strip()

for a in chain.from_iterable(fgen(line) for line in fgen('master.txt')):
    print(a)
```